# How to add datat to MySQL from CGI script with static html?

Tags: html, mysql, apache, perl

I have a CGI script that reads an HTML file. The HTML file is located in directory called `htdocs` and CGI file is located in directory called `cgi-bin`. I can access the html form from the web and when I submit I see the result I expect, but when I check MySQL the table has a new blank line.

I usually put CGI and HTML in same file because I find it easy, but I was wondering how I can do same action with CGI and HTML in different files. Here is my CGI file code:

```
    #!/usr/bin/perl -w

use DBI;

$db="user1";
$user="user1";
$passwd="P@ssw0rd";
$host="db-mysql.system1";
$connectionInfo="dbi:mysql:$db;$host";

#print HTTP Header
print "Content-type:text/html\n\n";

if ($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq "GET") {
    &parseform();
    &insertperson();
}
#else {
#   &parseform();
#   &insertperson();
#   exit;
#}

sub parseform {
    read(STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'});
    @pairs = split(/&/, $buffer);
    foreach $pair (@pairs) {
        ($name, $value) = split(/=/, $pair);
        $value =~ tr/+/ /;
        $value =~ s/%([a-fA-F0-9][a-fA-F0-9])/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
        $FORM{$name} = $value;
}

sub insertperson {
    $insert=qq~insert person(name,email,age,color)
        values('name','email','age','color')~;
    $dbh=DBI->connect($connectionInfo,$user,$passwd);
    $sth=$dbh->prepare($insert);
    if ($sth->execute()) {
        &displaysuccess;
    }
    else {
        &displayfail;
    }
    $dbh->disconnect0;
}

sub displaysuccess {
    print qq~<html>\n
        <head>
        <title>Person</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h2>Record Added</h2>
        </body>
        </html>
    ~;
}   

sub displayfail {
    print qq~<html>\n
        <head>
        <title>Person</title>
        </head>
        <body>
        <h2>Record Not Added</h2>
        </body>
        </html>
    ~;
}
```

[image: MySQL]

Comment: Replace `insert person` to `insert into person`. You current `insert` statement is not a valid sql syntax.

Comment: @Dekel — http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html — The `into` is just sugar. It's optional.

Comment: Don't write Perl without `use strict;` and `use warnings;`

Comment: Don't parse form data manually. [We have modules for that](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/CGI/lib/CGI.pod)

Comment: @Quentin, is it specific to mysql?

Comment: Danger! This code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Comment: @Quentin I have to parse form data manually. My question is how do I insert information into MySQL database when I have separate files for CGI and HTML? Is my syntax correct for checking if method is `GET`?

Comment: @Quentin The code works, but it adds an empty blank line in MySQL table!

Comment: The problem is not with two separate files... you can try and combine the files to see that you will still get the same problem.

Comment: @Dekel I usually put CGI and HTML is same file, but this time I want to see how I can do same thing with two different files! When I put them in single file I have `if ($ENV{REQUEST_METHOD} eq "GET") { &showform(); exit;} else { &parseform(); &insertperson(); exit;}` Because I have HTML in different location I think I have to change syntax and put `insertperson` and `parseform` if `REQUEST_METHOD` is `GET`!

Comment: And again - even if you put everything in 2 file - I really don't think it will work as you expect.

Comment: @Dekel What do you think is wrong with my code? Because I don't get any error!

Comment: You claim _The code works_ but I get `Possible unintended interpolation of @ssw0rd in string at x.pl line 7.
Missing right curly or square bracket at x.pl line 70, at end of line
  (Might be a runaway multi-line ~~ string starting on line 61)
syntax error at x.pl line 70, at EOF
x.pl had compilation errors.` Please **paste** code here **instead of typing it in**.

Comment: @HassenFatima: "I have to parse form data manually" - why? What is imposing such a ridiculous restriction on you?

Comment: And can I just point out that you should probably declare some of your columns as "not null" - that will prevent Perl from accidentally inserting blank lines.

Answer (score 3):

1. Perl is case sensitive.

You used the variable `$FORM` to set values, but later on you use `$form` (in `'$form{name}','$form{email}','$form{age}','$form{color}'`).

Change them to `'$FORM{name}','$FORM{email}','$FORM{age}','$FORM{color}'`

2. The `$FORM` variable is local to the `parseform` routine (therefor - it is **not** available inside the `insertperson` routine).

Comment: I have changed `form` to `FORM`, but still the issue is there. I have posted a screenshot of what I see in MySQL table in my question!

Comment: 1. what about the second part? 2. update the question with the **updated** code

Comment: And you completely ignored the 2nd part in my answer

Comment: I only changed `form` to `FORM`. I did not add or remove anything else!

Comment: So your `FORM` is still **local** and available **only** inside the `parseform` routine.

Comment: Yes, I forgot to update that. I have changed now, so in MySQL I get name, email, age, color! I am updating the image for MySQL too!

Comment: I really don't understand what you did in this change... you completely removed the usage of variables (and just used the string 'name', etc). Do you know what is local/global variable?

Comment: I new with perl programming , so I apologize for silly mistakes. I thought you meant `FORM` can only be used in `parseform`, so removed it!

Comment: If you remove it you no longer use this variable **at all**. Check here about global/local variables: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972310/global-variable-subroutine-variable-question-in-perl

Comment: @Dekel: Why do you think that `%FORM` is local to `parseform()`? It's not declared at all, so Perl will create it as a global (i.e. package) variable.

Comment: @DaveCross, Didn't remember that (long time didn't touch perl :) ) Thanks for that info!

Answer (score 0):

Here's the subroutine you use to insert the data into the database:

```
sub insertperson {
    $insert=qq~insert person(name,email,age,color)
        values('name','email','age','color')~;
    $dbh=DBI->connect($connectionInfo,$user,$passwd);
    $sth=$dbh->prepare($insert);
    if ($sth->execute()) {
        &displaysuccess;
    }
    else {
        &displayfail;
    }
    $dbh->disconnect;
}
```

The SQL you execute is:

> insert person(name,email,age,color) values('name','email','age','color')

That's inserting hard-coded values into your database. You want to insert data from your `%FORM` hash.

```
%insert = "insert person(name,email,age,color)
           values('$FORM{name}','$FORM{email}',
                  '$FORM{age}','$FORM{color}')";
```

But this code is a **terrible** idea. You are taking data from an unknown user and inserting it into an SQL statement. That's an [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com/) waiting to happen.

A far better approach is to use bind variables and extra parameters to `execute()`.

```
sub insertperson {
    $insert = "insert person(name,email,age,color)
               values(?, ?, ?, ?)";
    $dbh=DBI->connect($connectionInfo,$user,$passwd);
    $sth=$dbh->prepare($insert);
    if ($sth->execute($FORM{name}, $FORM{email},
                      $FORM{age},$FORM{color})) {
        &displaysuccess;
    }
    else {
        &displayfail;
    }
    $dbh->disconnect;
}
```

An even better idea is to look at [DBIx::Class](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBIx::Class) - but I'm guessing that's a step too far at this point.

Some other points on your code:

- Please replace `-w` with `use warnings` and add `use strict` (you will then need to declare all of your variables).
- Please use CGI.pm to parse your CGI parameters and print the CGI header.
- Please stop using `&` to call subroutines. Something like `displaysuccess()` looks more recognisable as a subroutine call and doesn't have hidden side effects that will bite you one day.
- Please use a templating engine (I recommend the [Template Toolkit](https://metacpan.org/release/Template-Toolkit)) to handle your HTML.
- Your HTML should really have an h1 element before the h2 element. You should use CSS to fix the appearance, rather than messing with the semantics.

Comment: actually the `'name', email','age'` etc is new, his original code was `'$FORM{name}', '$FORM{email}', '$FORM{age}'`

Comment: Yes, I know. I looked at the edit history. The original code used `$form{name}`, etc. which wouldn't have worked. When he switched to `$FORM{name}`, etc., if should have started working.

Comment: Thats exactly what I told him, but he said it didn't work (you can check my answer).

Comment: I have. But he's obviously very confused. Who knows what tests he actually ran :-/